# like button for posts in jekyll

Tags: jekyll, blogs

I want to add a like button, for every post on the homepage of my jekyll blog
I didn't find any plugin. I don't want any facebook's like button that connects to company's/product page likes.

I want a like button which is independent from any social platforms and only relates to post.

Something like this
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer: you can't.

Long answer: your button will have store the "likes" somewhere (usually a database), which is by definition a dynamic process. Jekyll can only generates static data.

You can bind your button to an external service, e.g. [LikeBtn](https://likebtn.com/en/) which provides such functionality (the free offer miss advanced features like statistics).

Whatever the service you choose, it will usually work by adding a javascript snippet, as with google analytics. You can see how to use google analytics with jekyll to help you (e.g. [here](https://michaelsoolee.com/google-analytics-jekyll/)).

Comment: Yes it is possible using Js and tools like firebase. https://xyzcoder.github.io/firebase/2019/03/17/firebase-real-time-database.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible to add a like button and track number of likes by writing your custom JavaScript code and a database to your Jekyll generated static sites.

So coming to the database as it is a static page and doesn't involve any server, it is not possible to interact with database directly but there is a way.
In my case I am making use of firebase. Firebase by Google provides us many capabilities like storage, database , hosting and also access to serverless architecture using functions.

So coming to the point, all you need to do is register with http://firebase.google.com 
Then create an app and then in your JavaScript add following code in head tag

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.9.0/firebase.js"></script>
<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  // TODO: Replace with your project's customized code snippet
  var config = {
    apiKey: "<API_KEY>",
    authDomain: "<PROJECT_ID>.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://<DATABASE_NAME>.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "<PROJECT_ID>",
    storageBucket: "<BUCKET>.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "<SENDER_ID>",
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);

var timestamp = new Date().valueOf();
            var obj = {};
            obj[timestamp] = "1";

            firebase.database().ref('/').update(obj)
</script>
```

For more details,
You can visit my blog on this topic

https://xyzcoder.github.io/firebase/2019/03/17/firebase-real-time-database.html

Note: we can also implement security restrictions on who can read and write data to our json store

Thanks,
Pavan